# iOS restores in-app purchase although no iTunes account is logged in

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

One of my iOS apps has been in the App Store for years, offering different non-consumable in-app purchase items.

Currently I am working on adding some new consumable items as well. Since the simulator does not support test purchasing I am running the test on my real device:

- The device is running iOS 12. Within the system settings I have logged our from my real iTunes account and **rebooted the device**.
- In AppStoreConnect I have created a new test user / iTunes Account and activated it
- After installing the new app version on the device using Xcode 10 I started the process to restore previous purchases using `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`

I expected that iOS would present an App Store login where I could use the credentials of the new test account. Instead `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is called with different transactions in `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` state. I assume that these are the real transactions I made with my real App Store account some time ago.

**How is this possible when being logged out from iTunes/App Store?**

The result is the same, even when I login to the test account within the system settings, reboot the device run the restore process than.

**Why are the transactions of my real account are restores while being logged in with another account (the test account)?**

**What can I do do force iOS to log out from my real account and use the test account instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Check **Settings->iTunes** & **App Stores** -> Scroll Down
here is **SANDBOX ACCOUNT** log out sandbox account too and everything will work

Comment: What is the OS version of your Phone? Because I can't see that option on my mobile.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did no know this option. Now it works as expected! @Jayachandra I see this option in iOS 12.